# Batch file doesn't seem to call other batch files correctly

Tags: batch-file, command-line, bitlocker

I'm trying to create a batch file that calls other batch files which unlock a specific drive on a server at start. I know the unlock scripts work. The drive unlocks as it should if I run them. But when I try to automate it by creating another batch script to call those scripts based on the server name, it fails to unlock. When running the script manually it tells me the called upon script has the incorrect unlock code.

I tried adding in the full name of the server I'm aiming for.

Instead of

```
If %computername% == "PartialServername*" Goto Servername
```

I changed it to

```
If %computername% == "Servername" Goto Servername
```

I also tried running it as:

```
If %computername% == "Servername" Call Servername.bat
```

And this worked, but not if I had multiple lines of `if`.

**Server Unlock.bat**

```
pushd "\\servername\scripts\unlock scripts\"
If %computerName% == "PartialServerName1*" Goto Servername
:Servername Call Servername.Bat
```

**Servername.bat**

```
manage-bde -unlock d: -recoverypassword *Recovery key here*
```

I expected it to call upon the batch file and unlock the drive, but instead the batch file calls upon the file and then says the recovery password is wrong.

Full script:

```
REM Created temporary network drive to the unlock scripts folder on vipre

pushd "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts\"

REM Checks the value of the Server name then goes to that section of the 
script REM to run the appropriate script
If %computerName% == "Bow*" Goto Bow
If %computerName% == "Del*" Goto Del
If %computerName% == "Fin*" Goto Fin
If %computerName% == "Gah*" Goto Gah
If %computerName% == "Gib*" Goto Gib
If %computerName% == "Kal*" Goto Kal
If %computerName% == "Ken*" Goto Ken
If %computerName% == "Lei*" Goto Lei
If %computerName% == "Lew*" Goto Lew
If %computerName% == "Lim*" Goto Lim
If %computerName% == "Loa*" Goto Loa
If %computerName% == "Mar*" Goto Mar
If %computerName% == "Ott*" Goto Ott
If %Computername% == "Pem*" Goto Pem
If %computerName% == "Ric*" Goto Ric
If %computerName% == "Sha*" Goto Sha
If %computerName% == "Wes*" Goto Wes
:Bow
Call Bow.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Del
Call Del.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Fin
Call Fin.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Gah
Call Gah.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Gib
Call Gib.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Kal
Call Kal.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Ken
Call Ken.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Lei
Call Lei.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Lew
Call Lew.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Lim
Call Lim.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Loa
Call Loa.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Mar
Call Mar.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Ott
Call Ott.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Pem
Call Pem.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Ric
Call Ric.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Sha
Call Sha.bat
Call DistributionRestart.bat
popd
:Wes
Call Wes.bat
popd
```

Comment: Also, you need to ensure that quoting is correct on the same side. For example: IF "%computerName%" == "PartialServerName1*".. notice quotes around %computerName%. However, without seeing the full script context I cannot tell what computerName's value might be

Comment: Sorry, but `if` does not support any kind of wildcards. Use `echo %computername%|findstr /b "PartialServerNa" && goto Servername` instead.

Comment: Also, it appears you are trying to match on a partial string. Looking for anything that begins with "PartialServerName". This isn't possible with the logic that you have entered, there may be some techniques to do what you want but the logic as shown won't work.

Comment: I tried again with the full server name so instead of
   If %computername% == "Partial"  Goto Servername
It now goes 
    If %computername% == "Servername" Goto Servername and I get the same thing, could I need to add something else to make it go to the approiate location?

Comment: And now.. I think it's because you need to add quotes around computername... and maybe make it case insensitive compare....  try.... IF /I "%computerName%" == "<full-name>" Goto xyz

Comment: @JohnRocha I tried the script with    If /I "%computerName%" == "Bowl" Goto Bowl and still got the same result.

Comment: @Compo What's the context of    `For %%A In (Bow Del Fin Gah Gib Kal Ken Lei Lew Lim Loa Mar Ott Pem Ric Sha Wes)Do If /I "%ComputerName:~,3%" == "%%A" (Call "%%A.bat" & If Not "%%A" == "Wes" Call DistributionRestart.bat )`
Would I need to include `pushd "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computername is an environment variable, and so the comparison needs to be case insensitive. Use the `/I` option to do a case insensitive search

---

You need to have equal quoting on both side of the equation

```
IF/I "%computername%" == "<value>" ....
.    ^              ^    ^       ^
.    ^              ^    ^       ^
```

Note the quotes around %computername% and around `<value>`.

---

The wild card logic won't work, but a simple technique is to use a substring compare. You are always comparing 3 characters so you can change the logic to something like:

```
if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Bow" .....
```

This starts at the beginning (index 0) and creats a string of length 3, and then compares that to Bow to do a case insensitive string comparison, where the quoting matches on both sides

Consider the following alternative script

1. one set of matching pushd/popd
2. Uses helper functions `withDistribRestart` and `noDistribRestart` to trigger the respective scripts where the passed in parameter is the name of the batch script to execute
3. Checks for and reports unexpected computer names

---

```
@ECHO OFF
GOTO :Main


REM =========================================================================
:Main
SETLOCAL
    SET "retVal=0"


    pushd "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts"


    if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Bow" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Bow
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Del" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Del
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Fin" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Fin
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Gah" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Gah
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Gib" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Gib
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Kal" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Kal
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Ken" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Ken
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Lei" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Lei
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Lew" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Lew
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Lim" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Lim
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Loa" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Loa
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Mar" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Mar
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Ott" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Ott
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Pem" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Pem
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Ric" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Ric
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Sha" (
        CALL :withDistribRestart Sha
    ) else if /I "%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%" == "Wes" (
        CALL :noDistribRestart Wes
    ) else (
        ECHO Unexpected COMPUTERNAME '"%COMPUTERNAME%"'
        SET "retVal=1"
    )

    popd
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B %retVal%)



REM ========================================================================
:withDistribRestart
SETLOCAL
    SET "PREFIX=%~1"

    CALL "%PREFIX%.bat"
    CALL "DistributionRestart.bat"
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)




REM ========================================================================
:noDistribRestart
SETLOCAL
    SET "PREFIX=%~1"

    CALL "%PREFIX%.bat"
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)
```

Comment: The only issue I've come across with this script so far is pushd won't map to the full path. It drops, the path is dropping after the word "Unlock" so instead of \\scriptserver\unlock scripts it tries to map to \\scriptserver\unlock" then defaults back to the default directory.
Edit: Just tried going to the directory by manually using the pushd command and it works, but not when run through the script.

Comment: My mistake. When I tested I used a different path. The pushd line should be replaced with `pushd "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts"` Notice that the path no longer ends with a `\`.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental misconception:

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

```
for %%a in (Bow Del Fin ....) do If /i "%computerName:~0,3%" == "%%a" (
 if /i "%%a" == "Del" (
  Call delsub.bat
  Call DistributionRestart.bat
 ) else (
  Call %%a.bat
  Call DistributionRestart.bat
 )
)
popd
```

Here, each of the values in the list is compared case-insensitively to the first 3 characters of `computername` and if a match is found, then execute the appropriate batches.

Since `del` is a keyword - and a dangerous one, `delete` I've also shown how to make an exception.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Usage of `setlocal/endlocal` combined with `exit /b` gives functionality similar to an end of procedure and doesn't need the `goto :eof`

Comment: @JohnRocha Certainly, you can use those facilities. My response addresses OP's structure where it appears that reaching a label marks the end of a procedure like reaching the end of a paragraph in COBOL returns to the *perform* (assuming *sections* and *perform though* are sensibly disallowed) The point is that to prevent the drop-through, use a *goto :eof*

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all of those `If` commands with:

```bat
GoTo %ComputerName:~,3% 2>NUL||Exit /B
```

However you can do all of that script in a single line too:

```bat
@PushD "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts" 2>NUL&&For %%A In (Bow Del Fin Gah Gib Kal Ken Lei Lew Lim Loa Mar Ott Pem Ric Sha Wes)Do @If /I "%ComputerName:~,3%"=="%%A" (Call "%%A.bat"&If /I Not "%%A"=="Wes" Call "DistributionRestart.bat")
```

You could of course split that over more lines for readability:

```bat
@Echo Off
PushD "\\scriptserver\unlock scripts" 2>NUL||Exit /B
For %%A In (Bow Del Fin Gah Gib Kal Ken Lei Lew Lim Loa Mar Ott Pem Ric Sha Wes
)Do If /I "%ComputerName:~,3%"=="%%A" (Call "%%A.bat"
    If /I Not "%%A"=="Wes" Call "DistributionRestart.bat")
```